# How to display title in colorbox?

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using the [Colorbox 7.x-2.8](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) to display contents. The colorbox is opened when an image is clicked. Inside, the description of the image is shown.  It renders/shows the whole content of the page but not the title itself.

The content title is also not showing in manage display, but it is on the manage fields. What other options can I do for this one?

Comment: Colorbox? How? Module? If so, please link that module. Library via your custom code? If so, please post that code. And so on. We need precise data to give meaningful answers.

Comment: oh sorry. I am using colorbox 7.x-2.8. the colorbox is called when an image is clicked, inside, the description of the image is shown.

Comment: **[Edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/137359/edit)**, please :)

Comment: Oh wait. I got it XD I just printed the title itself. d'oy XD But why am I getting a "1" after I printed the $node->title?

Comment: "But why am I getting a "1" after I printed the $node->title?" - show us the code if you want us to have a chance to guess...